# SQL GroupBy query returns error

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a SQL table that contains the following columns:

```
ID, VehRegID, RenewalLetterNumber, DateLetterSent
 1    200675    1                    2014-02-01  
 4    200675    1                    2014-03-21  
 7    200675    2                    2014-04-11
 9    201175    1                    2014-02-21  
 12   201175    1                    2014-03-31  
 65   201175    2                    2014-04-11  
 88   201100    1                    2014-05-18  
 97   201100    2                    2014-05-21
```

What I am looking to accomplish is:

If a VehRegID appears 3 times in the table, then get the Min(DateLetterSent) and update the RenewalLetterNumber = 3

The query I have is:

```
SELECT VehRegID, MIN(DateLetterSent) As [EarliestDate]  
FROM tblTempRenewal  
WHERE VehRegID IN  
(SELECT VehRegID, Count(*) Total  
FROM tblTempRenewal  
GROUP BY VehRegID
HAVING Count(*) = 3)  
GROUP BY VehRegID
```

I get an error "Incorrect syntax newr )"

I can't figure out where the error is. Any suggestions?

Comment: Remove the `Count(*) Total` from the Subquery

Comment: having Count(*) or count(1)= 3

Comment: So wait, if `VehRegID` appears exactly 3 times, you want to **update**, or you just want to do a `SELECT`?

Comment: @MartinK. put your response in the answer section and I will accept. That worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `Count(*) Total` from the Subquery. The Subquery in the `IN` Operator can only have one column in the Resultset.

Answer (score 3):

The error is a result of you returning two columns  in your sub-select for the IN clause.  You can only return one column in that query because it is part of the IN clause.  Below I removed the COUNT(*) from your sub-query.

```
SELECT VehRegID
,      MIN(DateLetterSent) As [EarliestDate]
FROM   tblTempRenewal
WHERE   VehRegID IN
        ( SELECT VehRegID

          FROM   tblTempRenewal
          GROUP
          BY     VehRegID HAVING count(*) = 3
        )
GROUP BY VehRegID
```

You can still use the having statement without selecting the count(*).

Answer (score 1):

I formatted your code a little differently and added `*` between `count()` and removed the inner `count` since it doesn't do anything for you:

```
SELECT VehRegID
,      MIN(DateLetterSent) As [EarliestDate]
FROM   tblTempRenewal
WHERE   VehRegID IN
        ( SELECT VehRegID
          FROM   tblTempRenewal
          GROUP
          BY     VehRegID
          HAVING count(*) = 3
        )
GROUP BY VehRegID
```

And I wonder whether you really need the subquery. So in the end it would become:

```
SELECT VehRegID
,      MIN(DateLetterSent) As [EarliestDate]
FROM   tblTempRenewal
GROUP
BY     VehRegID
HAVING count(*) = 3
```

Comment: Looking the revisions of the question, op had `*` in his original query, but it got removed because it wasn't formatted

Comment: @podiluska What does "the reverse was the case" means?. And [this](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/999e630b-66c2-4871-94b8-1c81a042c610/view-source) is the code of the first revision, the `*` is there, it got removed because it was taken as if it was italics

Comment: @PatrickHofman Did you actually look at the source code of the first revision?

Comment: I did look at the revision, but you are right. They actually were there.

Comment: Did you try the last one?

Answer (score 0):

Can we simplify this query?

```
SELECT VehRegID
    ,MIN(DateLetterSent)
FROM tblTempRenewal
GROUP BY VehRegID
HAVING count(0) = 3
```